# Scheduling of .KTR (Spoon) Files through Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, batch-processing, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I need to Schedule  **.KTR (Pentaho-Spoon)**  Files through Windows Task Scheduler
as We don't have any java embedded application .

I need to schedule my **.KTR** file in Mid-night.
I wrote the Script but isn't working.Here My Spoon folder is in D Drive 
and `"D:\Spoon\Stable\data-integration\kitchen.sh this is my SPOON Location"`

Please correct the script for me so that I can schedule the task easily

This is the script I saved as Schedule.bat ----

```
D:\Spoon\Stable\data-integration\kitchen.sh \pan.bat /file=
D:\Spoon\Stable\data-integration\kitchen.sh \Mid12.ktr /log=D:\Spoon\Stable\data-integration\kitchen.sh \logs\myTransfo.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by writing a Pan.bat

cd /d E:\Stablepent\data-integration
pan.bat "/file:E:\Spoon_Jobs\T_TEST.ktr" > runlog.txt